# How to inject arguments from a custom decorator to a command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

I'm working on a bot which keeps track of various text-based games in different channels. Commands used outside the channel in which the relevant game is running should do nothing of course, and neither should they activate is the game is not running (for example, when a new game is starting soon). Therefore, almost all my commands start with the same few lines of code

```
@commands.command()
async def example_command(self, ctx):
    game = self.game_manager.get_game(ctx.channel.id)
    if not game or game.state == GameState.FINISHED:
        return
```

I'd prefer to just decorate all these methods instead. Discord.py handily provides a system of "check" decorators to automate these kinds of checks, but this does not allow me to pass on the `game` object to the command. As every command needs a reference to this object, I'd have to retrieve it every time again anyway, and ideally I'd like to just pass it along to the command.

My naive attempt at a decorator looks as follows

```
def is_game_running(func):
    async def wrapper(self, ctx):
        # Retrieve `game` object here and do some checks
        game = ...

        return await func(self, ctx, game)

    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__

    return wrapper

# Somewhere in the class
@commands.command()
@is_game_running
async def example_command(self, ctx, game):
    pass
```

However this gives me the quite cryptic error "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing."

I've tried a few variants of this, using `*args` etc... but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

discord.py has provided a convenient [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Context.bot) attribute for the context object that lets you get the bot instance from the context. You can get your game from there.

I'll use discord.py's check system for the example.

```py
def is_game_running():
    def predicate(ctx):
        game = ctx.bot.game_manager.get_game(ctx.channel.id)

        ... # do some checks

        return result # result of the check. Must be true or false
    return commands.check(predicate)

@commands.command()
@is_game_running()
async def example_command(self, ctx, game):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the issue is actually that I'd also like to pass along this `game` object to the command handler. Otherwise, I'd have to do the lookup again inside the handler, and then it's hardly worth it